# MySQL: Insert com condicional

Tags: mysql

Preciso realizar a seguinte situação abaixo, mas ao executar tenho o erro:

**/* Erro SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO produto_seriais(serial_id) VALUES(
        SELECT id FROM seriais WHERE serial =' at line 5 */**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (
    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM seriais WHERE serial = '2020'
) > 1
THEN
    (INSERT INTO produto_seriais(serial_id) VALUES(
        SELECT id FROM seriais WHERE serial = '2020'
    ))
ELSE (
    INSERT INTO seriais (serial) VALUE('2020');
    SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO produto_seriais (serial_id) VALUES (@last_id_in_table1);
)
END;
```

O caso é o seguinte:

Vou buscar na tabela "seriais" pelo serial "X". Se ele já existir, salvo seu ID na tabela "produto_seriais". Se não existir (o serial), vou salvar o mesmo, recuperar seu ID e salvar em "produto_seriais". Alguma sugestão de como fazer isso?

Nota importante: esta rotina será rodará milhares de vezes a cada execução (10.000 ou mais, dependendo da quantidade de seriais).

Comment: introduza um espaço entre produto_seriais e (serial_id):  `produto_seriais (serial_id)`